# How can I access steal time data in Solaris SunOS 5.10

Tags: performance, virtual-machines, solaris, performance-monitoring

I think that the version of Solaris that we are running is too old to report steal time in top.  Is there a way to get this information on this older version of Solaris.  Here is the basic version info:

```
-bash-3.2$  uname -aX
SunOS sekritname 5.10 Generic_150400-59 sun4v sparc sun4vSystem = SunOS
Node = sekritname
Release = 5.10
KernelID = Generic_150400-59
Machine = sun4v
BusType = <unknown>
Serial = <unknown>
Users = <unknown>
OEM# = 0
Origin# = 1
NumCPU = 32
```

I do not have any real expertise the these Sun VM systems, so I might be misunderstanding things and there might be a better way to do what I need in this situation.  Applying my Intel mental model I suspect that we are getting crowded off the CPU, but how can I measure that?

**Update**

Forgive the Intelish terminology. We are basically running two VMs on a single blade where one is an application server and the other provides SSO support of the application.  We have moments where the application server slows down significantly and we also have moments where the third party SSO application goes off into the weeds.

There are also silos and politics involved, so I do not have visibility into the SSO host or the actual hardware layer.

My current operating hypothesis is that when the SSO application goes crazy it occupies the CPU so much that the application server is not able to get enough real compute time to keep up with the load.  I analyzed the GC logs from the application and one thing that stood out were entries like this:

```
[Times: user=0.71 sys=1.36, real=1.47 secs]
```

That is with 10 parallel GC worker threads, normally `user >> real >> sys` and  one cause of the odd time pattern is a VM where you cannot get enough CPU.  (We are not swapping and the systems are all SSD based, so IO waits are not an issue.)

At this point I need to get data to help prove out this theory, and in my Linux mind I would just check the st% in top.  Googling also says in the modern version of Solaris I could do the same thing.  My problem is that we are not running that modern version of Solaris.

Comment: Is this Solaris running in a VM? If so you need to look at monitoring on the host using `zonestat` and other tools. Oracle provide lots of resources to manage containers and zones,and it is rather different from Intel CPUs.

Comment: Don't use `top`, use `prstat`:  http://www.brendangregg.com/DTrace/prstatvstop.html  And what do you need "steal time" for?  You're not looking at VMs running on another host OS.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I updated the question with more information about why I feel I need the "Steal time" for.  I am open to better options.

Comment: Well, you're running on a `sun4v` SPARC server with 32 CPUs.  That's almost certainly CPU(s) in the ["UltraSPARC T" series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARC_T-Series), probably an UltraSPARC T1 running on an older T1000 or T2000 server.  So you're not running x86-style VMs.  You may be running zones, however.  What's the output from `zonename`?  And do you have root access?  How long do your slow moments last?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't have root although I can talk to someone who does.  I do not have zonename or prstat in my path.  As for the slowdowns some are short < 1 min, but I also have examples that go for 30 minutes.  We did increase the number of cpus to 40 and allocated more memory to the application.  That helped, but really is not very meaningful.  I am duplicating these things in our QA environment (with 32 CPUs), but is still don't have root there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your real problem here appears to be your performance slowdowns.  And steal-time likely is meaningless on a Solaris 10 T1000/T2000 server.

To find out if you're running in a zone, use the `/usr/bin/zonename` command (location might be different on different versions of Solaris - also check `/bin`, `/sbin/`, and `/usr/sbin`.)  If `zonename` returns anything other than `global`, you're running in a zone.

If, for some reason you don't have access to the `zonename` command, there are several `ps` commands you can use to see if you're in a zone.  First, look for `init`:

```
ps -ef | grep init
```

If that doesn't locate an `init` process with a PID of `1`, you're in a zone.  You can also look for `zsched` (IIRC):

```
ps -ef | grep zsched
```

If that returns one process that is it's own parent (both PID and PPID are the same and greater than `1`) then you're running in a zone.

If you're in a zone, you may be running into resource limitations that slow you down.  That's not likely to be the case, though.

What *else* is running on the server, though?  Including other zones.  I've seen really nasty performance issues on Sun T-series servers similar to what you're describing, caused by interactions between the ZFS ARC and applications that use huge memory pages - such as an Oracle database.

The ZFS ARC uses 4k memory pages, so it fragments memory - and it will fragment **ALL** the memory on your server.  If your server gets into that state and a process requires a significant amount of large memory pages, the kernel has to coalesce a bunch of small pages into large ones, which involves moving around a lot of memory.  And it's all done single-threaded.  And any single thread on an early T-series server is **S-L-O-W** as the servers were designed to handle a huge number of threads with large latencies - such as a web server or database server that handles a lot of connections across a network.

So the kernel goes into long periods where pretty much all it does is coalesce small pages of memory into large pages.

Then the ZFS ARC gets the pages back after they large-page-using process is done with them and they get fragmented.

I suspect you may be having this exact same problem.

To find out, run

```
echo ::memstat | mdb -k
```

as root, in the global zone if you're running zones.  If your free memory is really low, you may be having this problem.

To find out, run the following dTrace script, again as root from the global zone to determine where the kernel is spending all its time:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s

profile:::profile-1001hz
/arg0/
{
    @[ stack() ] = count();
}
```

Copy that to a file, say `hot.d`, set it executable (`chmod 755 hot.d`) and run it as root from the global zone:

```
./hot.d
```

Run it when you're experiencing your slowdowns.  Let it run for a good 10-20 seconds if not longer after it emits `matched 1 probe`, then break it with `CTRL-C`.  It will then emit a *lot* of output, most of which you don't care about.  The last handful of stack traces output, however, will be the most common ones sampled, which will tell you where the kernel is spending all its time.

That will definitively tell you where your problem is.  It may not be precise enough to fully solve it and you may need to do more investigation, but you will know where to look.

If you see a lot of stack traces with `idle` or `wait` in it, you've got a user-space issue.  You might be able to identify that by replacing `stack()` in the above dTrace script with `ustack()` to get the user stack.

And if you're seeing lots of stack traces with `coalesce` in the function names, the kernel is spending all its time creating large memory pages.  The fix for that is to free up memory, most likely by limiting the ZFS ARC size, perhaps even severely.  I've had to [kneecap](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kneecap) the ZFS ARC on a few servers, down to under 1 GB, to stop it from killing performance.

Comment: Ah-ha, so this is not a VM model but a container model.  That makes so much more sense! You have also given me some tools and a good hypothesis to take back to the Unix admins. Thanks!

Comment: @Ukko Glad to help. And yes, Solaris zones are a container model - there's only one copy of the kernel running, and it's shared between the zones. Also, you may have an IO issue if you see `idle` or `wait` in kernel stack traces from the dTrace script - I missed that possibility.